# I want to do a piano tutorials platform and I have copyrights question

Tags: copyright, music

We are working on a solution to learn the piano, like [this one](https://playlumi.com/), or [this one](https://latouchemusicale.com/en/).

I have read that for each song that I will add on the platform, I'll need to have the permission of the artist (and we will probably need to pay a fee each time a song is played or something like this).
Is it true even if we are **not playing sound** on the platform? (We will just show lights from our physical object to indicate the pianist how to play a song). Or is it considered as **fair use**?

If it is the case, is there a way to have a contract with a lot of artists easily? Or do we need to contact each artist individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different rights involved. The music, in musical notation form, has copyright. The typeset sheet music itself may have a different copyright. Any recordings of the music may have separate rights.

Many artists will be signed up with a synch agent and if you contact a synch agent they will be able to licence music to you from their portfolio of artists.

Or you need to stick to out-of-copyright or royalty-free music, or compose your own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know where we can find the synch agents?

Comment: If the composer died more than 70 years ago, the copyright expires.

Comment: I found several by googling 'sync agent'. And although the composer's copyright may (depending on jurisdiction) expire after 70 years, other rights may not.

Comment: Good to know, thanks